# Show series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Show that the series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n!^n}{n^{n^2}}$$ converges.

I tried the ratio test but didn't come to a conclusion.
Wolfram says the series converges by comparison but I don't know what series to compare to.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/232501/ which applies the Root Test.

Answer (score 0):

Since by the Stirling approximation$$n\ln n!-n^2\ln n\in n(n\ln n-n+o(n))-n^2\ln n=-n^2(1-o(1)),$$we have a superexponentially decaying upper bound on the $n$th term, so the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

By Stirling's approximation
$$\frac{n!}{n^{n}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}$$

so $$\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{n!}{n^{n}} = 0$$

In particular, for $n$ sufficiently large, $$\frac{n!^n}{n^{n^2}} = \left( \frac{n!}{n^{n}} \right)^n \leq \frac{n!}{n^{n}} \sim \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}$$

and since the series $\sum \frac{\sqrt{2\pi n}}{e^n}$, converges, then by comparison, the series
$$\sum \frac{n!^n}{n^{n^2}} $$
also converges.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Stirling the simpler is to go for AM-GM inequality followed by rough majoration

$$(n!)^{\frac 1n}\le \frac 1n\times\frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac{n+1}2\le \frac{2n}3$$ for $n$ large enough.

The term of your series is then to be compared to $(\frac 23)^{n^2}$